# Need help logging on to 192.168.1.1

Tags: linux, router, wireless-router, ip, wireless-access-point

trying to reset my security password- and same problem as listed- tried using admin for admin and password for password at  `http://192.168.1.1`  but seem to have locked myself out.
What should I do to unlock?

Comment: What is the make and model of your router?

Answer (score 3):

When you reset a device to its standard, the default username and password will be used.

This can be `admin` / `admin`, `admin` / , `admin` / `password` or any combination.

The best thing to do is look for the model and make of the device, and google for that + default password. Also, if you have the booklet, it will also mention what the default username and password is. Mostly used is `admin` / `admin`

Answer (score 1):

If you have reset your device to factory defaults then the username and password should be on the back of the device, if you know the make/model of the device you can also go to [this website](http://portforward.com/default_username_password/) and lookup the default username and password for your default.

Some of them most common ones are

- admin , blank
- admin , admin
- admin , password
- admin , root
- root , root